# Orion Context Broker How to filter an object by name contains a keyword

Tags: fiware-orion

We are using Orion Context Broker as our database.
Recently, We have meet an requirement that user want to find a City by name of this City container a keyword.

For example:

We have city name likes this. Hanoi, Madrid, London, Barcelona, Paris, Lyon.

If user type: "on", we should show Lyon, London.

The city object like this.

```
 {
            "type": "City",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "city1",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "London"
                }
            ]
        }
```

So I am wondering if any queryContext filtering can help us to sort out this case.
I have done some research and there is no good sounds on this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you possibly help to take a look? @fgalan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idPattern` in `GET /v2/entities` which value is a regular expression. Thus the following query:

```
GET /v2/entities?idPattern=on
```

should return any City with the "on" substring in its id.

**EDIT:** if you want to apply a pattern to the value of some attribute, then you have to use `q` query parameter and the `~=` NGSIv2 Simple Query Operator. Something like this:

```
GET /v2/entities?q=colour~=or
```

Comment: Hi fgalan, Happy to see your comment here.

Comment: Hi fgalan, regarding the expression "colour~=or" is it case sensitive or case insensitive ? and the "~=" does not support number string is it?

Comment: With regards to the first question, it is case sensitive. With regards to second question, I'm afraid I'm not getting your point. Could you provide an explanatory example, please?

Comment: Hi fgalan, I means This "the ~= NGSIv2 Simple Query Operator" has only support for string attribute, is it? if i have an expression like this colour~=255, It return correct result?

Comment: Hi fgalan, sorry to make you confuse. I have create a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388850/orion-context-broker-using-match-pattern-with-number

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that we use ~= operation to do that.

Please see the follow quote.

Match pattern: ~=. The value matches a given pattern, expressed as a regular expression, e.g. color~=ow. For an entity to match, it must contain the target property (color) and the target property value must match the string in the right-hand side, 'ow' in this example (brown and yellow would match, black and white would not). This operation is only valid for target properties of type string.

http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/
Section: Simple Query Language

Many thanks.

Comment: I have added my original answer to include some information related to that that I hope may be helpful.